# Matplotlib does not save figures all figures with axes

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

Using Matplotlib, I am looping through a list of different settings and visualize the results. Below you see the two graphs that I want to visualize and a picture of the output in my IDE (Spyder 4).

```
def plot_svd_graph_2D(self, directory):
    ypoints0 = np.array(np.sort(self.svd_data[:,0]))
    ypoints1 = np.array(np.sort(self.svd_data[:,1]))
    
    plt.plot(np.arange(0.0, len(ypoints0), 1),ypoints0, label='SV1', linestyle = 'dotted')
    plt.plot(np.arange(0.0, len(ypoints1), 1),ypoints1, label='SV2', linestyle = 'dotted')
    
    plt.xlabel('Data points')
    # Set the y axis label of the current axis.
    plt.ylabel('singular value')
    # Set a title of the current axes.
    plt.title("Sorted sv's "+self.setting)
    # show a legend on the plot
    plt.legend()
    plt.grid()
    plt.savefig(directory+self.setting+'SSV.png')
    plt.show()
    return
```

The output of the above code looks as follows:

[image]

```
    def plot_cluster_datapoints_graph(self, directory):
        fig=plt.figure()
        ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])
        ax.scatter(self.svd_data[:,0], self.svd_data[:,1], color='b', s = 0.2, label = 'Datapoints' )
        ax.scatter(self.cluster_centers[:,0], self.cluster_centers[:,1], s=8, color='r', label = 'Cluster centers')
        plt.title('Data point and clusters for 2 factors'+self.setting)
        plt.legend()
        plt.grid()
        plt.xlabel('Dimension 0')
        plt.ylabel('Dimension 1')
        plt.savefig(directory+self.setting+'-CD.png')
        plt.show()
        return
```

And for this code, the output looks like this:

[image]

While calling a method, I also save the plots. The first picture is saved as is shown in the output in my IDE, however the second image is saved as follows (without titles and axes:

[image]

Why are the graphs shown correctly in my IDE (with labels and titles), but not saved correctly? And what can I do so that they will be saved correclty?

Comment: `ax=fig.add_axes([0,0,1,1])` initializes an axes instance that spans the whole figure. The saved figure is hence the "correct" one and your IDE is technically displaying the figure incorrectly. You can initialize the axes such that there is some room for the labels for example with `ax=fig.add_axes([0.2, 0.2, 0.6, 0.6])`.

Comment: That works, thank you! If you make this an answer, then I can accept/upvote it.

Comment: I appreciate the offer but don't worry about it. It was just a small bug and I have plenty of internet points. Happy hacking.